# How to deploy asp.net core 2.1 MVC application as windows service using topshelf

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment, topshelf

I want to deploy an asp.net core 2.1 MVC application as a window service using top shelf. 
Is it possible? If yes please share how. Not able to find anything good on web regarding .net core + mvc with topshelf.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched the web (Google/Bing/Whatever) for help first? I did a search for "asp.net core topshelf service" and found many blog posts showing how to do this, including [this one](https://medium.com/@jackwild/net-core-windows-services-with-topshelf-74e8bfc3315e)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a need for Topshelf to run dotnet core applications as Windows Service.

Dotnet core offers different hosting models.

[Help link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)